# Error when running sitespeed.io with chrome : Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, graphite

I was running this command on the terminal

```
$ sitespeed.io -u http://cybercom.com  -b chrome
```

but always facing this error, I have tried many times but in vain cannot figure out the problem

```
message: 'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n (Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243 (0bfa1357514444f1ddb82bf70944f96),platform=Linux 3.13.0-65-generic x86_64)
```

knowing that

1-Os version : Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

2-my google chrome version is

```
$ google-chrome -version Google Chrome 46.0.2490.71
```

3-chrome driver version

```
$ chromedriver -version ChromeDriver 2.10.267518
```

but in the message error it is "Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243" .... I didn´t understand why they aren´t the same version ?

Google chrome version is not supported neither with chromedriver=2.16 nor with ChromeDriver 2.10.

```
----------ChromeDriver v2.16 (2015-06-08)----------
Supports Chrome v42-45

----------ChromeDriver v2.10 (2014-05-01)----------
Supports Chrome v33-36
```

what should I do in this case ?

I appreciate your help . Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you have two drivers installed on different paths?

However: upgrade to latest chrome driver 2.20 and it should work with your Chrome version. You can find it here: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.20/chromedriver_linux64.zip

Comment: I have removed the old version of the chromedriver 2.16.
when i rerun the commande to fetch timing i always have the same error although I´m using chromedrive supported by my google chrome `Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 `